# Display the HTML from a local page as a text-string using an XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript

I have two webpages on my local server, and I would like to display the html from `webpage-1` as a string on `webpage-2` using an XMLHttpRequest object. Despite the lengthy documentation, and the history of posts on SO related to this subject, I have been unable to accomplish this simple exercise on my own. This is most likely due to my misunderstanding of the XMLHttpRequest and of JavaScript. Maybe my question could help clear this issue up for other people also. So here is my code:

Here is my code for `webpage-1`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body><script>

<h1> Hello World! </h1>

</script></body></html>
```

Here is my code for `webpage-2`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body><script>
    var theUrl = http://localhost/website-2/;
    function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
        var xmlHttp = null;

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
    document.write(theUrl);
</script></body></html>
```

I would expect the `webpage-2`to look like this in the browser

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: You are not invoking the function. So do invoke the `httpGet()` function to get the result  write `document.write(httpGet(theUrl));` instead of `document.write(theUrl);` it will always display `http://localhost/website-2/`

Comment: And you are not escaping anything here, but writing plain html strings into a html document. That won't display it as text.

Comment: Thank you all, I will look at this tomorrow. This looks like good advice. If you would like to answer the question, I will mark the correct solution.